# UDP with mulicast sockets over wireless network

Tags: c, udp, multicastsocket

I wrote a simple udp server client application with multicast sockets. Server is sending packets to three clients every 6 ms . Packet
size is 1200 bytes. This is 166,66 packets per second. Whenever one of the client detects a missing packet, it will send a NACK packet to the server via unicast 
.

**First test:**
Server and three clients were connected to the router TP-Link TL-WDR4300 (dd-wrt) via ethernet and everything worked fine.

**Second test:**
Only server was connected to the router via Ethernet and other clients were connected via wireless 2.4 GHz and with fixed channel. Two problems arrived
with wireless: **First problem** is packet loss, clients are receiving just 50% of packets. And losses appear in bursts, for example 400 packets are received,
200 are lost etc. **Second problem** is that when clients are sending back NACK packets to the server which I can see on wireshark but my application can't receive them.
This is strange because the code is the same as it was when clients were connected via Ethernet. So, any ideas ? I would be thankful

Server code:

```
while (1) {

    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(sd, &readfds);

    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    rv = select(sd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

    while (rv == 1) {

        nack_processing(sd);
        rv = select(sd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);


    }
}
return 0;

}
```

I also made updates to decrease traffic:
Packet size : 800 bytes
Inter arrival time between packets : 10 ms
= 100 packets per second = 0.076 MB /s

and I measured traffic at server and client sides:
Server ~ 10 MB/s
Clients ~ 5 MB /s

Everything seems fine

Comment: Are the packets going via same path ? Else it may be an issue with multicast configuration for some n/w element in the path

Comment: UDP is not a reliable transport so it is possible for packets to be dropped.  Secondly in most cases UDP broadcasts are throttled by network nodes so that a broadcast is only visible within a particular sub-net of devices that are on the same cable or the same side of a wireless router.

Comment: There are a number of reasons for dropping UDP packets one of which is the network stack runs out of available network packet buffers.  So if you have a lot of traffic and a network node is unable to transfer already received data before more data comes in, packets will be dropped.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this with path...All packets are send to the multicast IP address. What is n/w path and where to check it?

Comment: I know that UDP is not reliable and that I can expect losses, but this bursts are very strange and uncommon and I think that problem is somewhere else. Richard I have decrease traffic that I'm sending and the problem still remains. Do you have any other ideas? Btw clients are on the same side of a wireless router

Comment: UDP is unreliable, and wireless is losses data more than wired, due to reasons like RF interference. To make data doesn't loose due to UDP buffer overflows, you should increase SO_RCVBUF option in receivers.

Comment: See this wikipedia article [UDP Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) and see also [what should I know about udp programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799068/what-should-i-know-about-udp-programming) and  [problems testing udp code outside of lan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799863/problems-testing-udp-code-outside-of-lan)

Comment: And for better testing, you must check to which value SO_RCVBUF set in linux machines, because you may get unpredicted results due to server config on buffer limits.

Comment: And remember most of time, losses in burst are due to buffer overflows or congestion, either in receives or in router/switches.

Comment: Could you update your question to include the changes you made to decrease traffic?  One question I have is the transmission rate of your wireless, what is the bandwidth?  It sounds to me like there is a combination of errors as well as insufficient bandwidth on the wireless if things worked fine with an ethernet cable.  The cable would typically provide more capacity and lower error rate.

Comment: I have updated the answer. And what is the reason if NACK's from clients are not arriving but I can see them in Wireshark...I set SO_RCVBUF to the 2 MB but situation is still same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are comparing two different interfaces/media. One is wired interface and another is wireless interface.

**Packet Loss in wireless networks:**

This can be due to multitude of reasons. However, the first immediate checkpoint should be SNR, RSSI and operating frequency/co-channel interference. A wifi-analyzer can almost take you near to the solution.

*Wireless router location* - Check whether the wireless router is centrally located within areas requiring coverage. Ensure to avoid coverage holes with proper overlapping of coverage areas. Ensure to avoid buildings in-between to reduce interference. Also, note that there is a relation between the distance and data rate for a user. The the nearer the user, the higher the data rate because of reduced path loss (because this in-turn increases the SNR).

*Type of Antenna* - An istropic antenna provides coverage area in the form a sphere. Dipole antenna provides coverage area in the form of doughnut. There are also various directional antennas.  Beware that the omni-directional antenna can lead to hidden node problem incase of large cell size. 
Antenna with focused beam can be helpful. Multi-sector directional antenna can give high capacity, range. The type of antenna, its location and antenna gain determines the radio transmission range and the coverage area.

*Communication channel / Operating frequency* - Presence of other APs operating in the same frequency in the same radio coverage area can cause interference. In such cases, the operating channel and channel separation should be changed accordingly to reduce interference if there are only 802.11 devices nearby.

*Power level* -  The higher power level can increase the range but if there are nearby APs, it can lead to interference. For higher capacity, APs might be close together, in such cases low power level is preferred to reduce interference.

*Other devices* - Interference can also be introduced by non-802.11 devices like microwave ovens, bluetooth, cordless phones etc.. In such cases, it is better to remove those devices or shield it to avoid interference.

Packet loss in terms of burst also seems to suggest that the stack is not able to handle bursty traffic and its  traffic shaping policy may be to simply drop such bursty packets. Double check if such traffic burst is generated.

**NACK not reaching the server :**
Again, this can be due to the transmission media related issues that can cause the NACK to be dropped over the air. Incase if the NACK has reached the host but not the server application/un-handled, then it can be due to the architecture of the server or stack related OS configuration.

**Typical steps for analyzing packet loss scenarios**

1. Check the firewall settings, OS configurations, router configurations and network hardware capabilities/ configs(throughput capability,operation mode), intermediate node config/ capabilities(MTU, routing/forwarding table)
2. On the wireless path, check location of AP, operating range(frequency), channel separation, SNR ,RSSI, antenna type/gain, coverage holes, distance from AP, presence of other 802.11 devices & non-802.11 devices in coverage area.
3. Check packet statistics on all input & output points of the various nodes & interfaces
4. Check packet statistics on all input & output points in applications/protocol layers
5. Repeated tests to identify the pattern of the packet loss with various combinations of throughput, packet size, duration of run, different applications, different payload sizes, different number of pkts, power level, AP location, channel... is also a way to determine the area of problem.

Comment: I will check most of this things and then I hope so post the solution. Thx